# Filter an array of objects based on value of inner object equaling value of outer object

Tags: json, select, jq

I have some data like this:

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "stuff": [
    {
      "foo": "baz"
    },
    {
      "foo": "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get the objects inside `stuff` which have the same value for `foo` as the outer object does. So in this case I would like to get:

```
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

How do I do this using `jq`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`jq`** approach:

```
jq '.foo as $foo | .stuff[] | select(.foo == $foo)' file.json
```

Comment: Ooh nice I did not know about `as`. This is perfect, thank you